# Как добавить новое View в уже существующие приложение

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Вопрос у меня больше архитектурный, у меня есть консольное приложение которое принимает данные обрабатывает и выводит их в консоль, но теперь я хочу его рассширить и добавить WebView, логика таже, но отображение в вебе, хочу реализовать с помощью Spring. Каким образом мне это сделать, может есть соответсвующий паттерн, или мне нужно делать новый Web модуль или просто создать класс WebView и засунуть его в пакет с ConsoleView?
Вот как сейчас выглядит структура моего проекта

[image]

Comment: MVC очень растяжимое понятие. Существует много способов разделить обязанности между `M`, `V` и `C` и самое главное организовать между ними взаимодействие. Например, что view что controller для swing приложения будут кардинально отличаться от web приложения. Поэтому на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить не зная, как MVC сейчас работает у вас, какие именно ответственности у компонентов.

Comment: @ Roman Konova, работает оно так. в классе Parser вычисляется вся логика, там всего два метода,  в классе Main я вывзываю метод parse из класса Parser и получаю обыный List, а далее передаю его в ConsoleView и там отрисовываю